# Program/Tool for more readable Java code?

Tags: java, coding-style, programming-languages, readability

I am currently looking for a program/tool that enhances the readability of a Java code. For example that it can convert the expression `x=y +z+ 3;` into `x = y + z + 3;` or the one of

```
public class Example
         {
             public static...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use the formatting capabilities of your IDE

Comment: Eclipse can do it. There are some useful hotkeys.

Comment: NetBeans is totally good for learners and beginners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse's "format on save" trigger will do that for you [see here](https://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/automatically-format-and-cleanup-code-every-time-you-save/)